# How to web scrape when page offset value never ends

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape player data off of https://sofifa.com using BeautifulSoup. Every page displays 60 players and so I use offset query param(for example https://sofifa.com/players?offset=60 shows 2nd page) to access all player's info.

One thing I noticed is that the offset value never ends(i.e. no matter how large the offset value I provide, it always shows me a page). Specifically, I noticed that for offset > 20000 or so, it always displays the 1st page(essentially after exhausting all players, it kinda rolls over to the 1st page and always displays that for all subsequent higher offset values). Try with https://sofifa.com/players?offset=20000000 to get an idea of what I mean.

I want to know if there is any way I can programmatically find out the last "valid" offset value; beyond which I am sure to get the 1st page back. That'll help me decide when I reached the end of the dataset.

Currently this is how I scrape:

```
for offset in range(0, 20000, 60):
  try:
    print("Processing page at offset " + str(offset))
    sofifa_url = "https://sofifa.com/players?offset=" + str(offset)
    # start scraping the page
    :
    :
  except Exception as e:
    print("Exception occured: " + str(e))
    continue
```

Comment: Kind of obvious / naive questions, but while retrieving the consecutive offsets, why don't you build your stop condition on the content? Here the each record is supposed to be unique, if I understand well.

Comment: One way of doing this would be checking if there's the next button and stop scraping when you've reached the last page.

Comment: @Maciek 2 things: The content on that website is dynamic. Gets updated regularly. Also keeping track of the scraped content to match against seems a bit memory intensive.

Comment: @baduker Instead of the next button on that website, "previous" button seems like a better way(since last page also has a "next"  button but 1st page has no "previous". I am aware of this as a possible solution but looking out to see if there are more sophisticated ones out there.

Comment: @knightcool: if the content is volatile, then I imagine, that the only thing you can do, is download its snapshot at a given point in time. In such case, it would be enough to track just one (the first) record, to discover that the offset has rolled over. 
Otherwise, if you want to have the content always up to date, you would need to continuously keep comparing your downloaded version with the online one, which of course would be much more troublesome than comparing just one record at the moment of downloading.

Comment: @baduker Did some more testing and noticed that using "next" or "previous" button is not too reliable on this website. Right now I see 4th page(https://sofifa.com/players?offset=240) not have a next button. Few mins back, it was the 3rd page with no "next" button.

Comment: @Maciek Hmm I noticed they keep adding more players on their first page. Maybe comparing the first record(which may also change while snapshot?) is the only way here.